# align bootstrap row to bottom of section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, row

I want to align a bootstrap row on a container-fluid layout into the bottom of each section on my site. I could create row a col-12 row and then use position: absolute and bottom: 0px, but it doesn't seem to be a good approach since it wouldn't be useful for other sections.

What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Update #1: I was trying to avoid the use of javascript and maintain the responsive design

Comment: can you post an example of the container-fluid? Do you mean you want the bootstrap row just to be after the container, because that seems like normal grid stuff? Or do you want it to always be anchored to the screen not the section?

Comment: You'll have better luck with an answer if you post your code, or better yet a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want the row to be at the bottom of the container-fluid?, if it's that then you can place the content of you section within rows and the last row is always going to be at the bottom, and if it's not that what you want then please paste your code, because a container-fluid has no fixed size as you might know so there's no way to have a row at the bottom of it if you don't have any content.